# Droidfish on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I cloned and ran the program from this source: https://github.com/fdelacruzsoto/md-chess-android

It syncs, but when I run the program, the build fails with this messsage:

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process
>   /Users/AyushArora/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with
>   arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19
>   NDK_OUT=/Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib
>   /Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/libgtb.so}
>   [x86] Compile        : gtb <= gtb-probe.c
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'
>
> make: ***
>   [/Users/AyushArora/AndroidStudioProjects/md-chess-android2/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs/gtb/gtb-probe.o]
>   Error 1

Answer (score -1):

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'

**Clang** does not support this argument. One possible solution is to downgrade your NDK to an older version which uses **gcc**, e.g. [NDK Revision 10e](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases).

Comment: Why downgrade instead of just not passing a meaningless flag?

Comment: If there are other issues that come up when compiling the project with Clang rather than GCC, you do not need to downgrade all the way back to r10. r17 is the furthest back you need to go.

Comment: I am not sure -mandroid is a meaningless flag or not, just be careful when you remove an already there machine dependent compiler flag.

Comment: It's meaningless for the Android compilers (Clang does not allow it, and GCC does not need it). It is default for Android GCC cross compilers: https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/master/gcc-4.9/gcc/config/linux-android.opt#22. If you're using a non-Android ARM GCC then it will maybe cause it to generate code for Android, but that's definitely not a tested configuration and you need the rest of the NDK sysroot anyway, so I'd hope no one is doing that.